# How to merge specific key to one array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get that value in the array with "clean_bin_number" and pull it out from each of the main arrays. And have only the values in one array.

Hopefully you guys can understand what I'm trying to do....

Here some code examples:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["clean_bin_number"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "1004445"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["clean_bin_number"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "3087762"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

I'd like to get a result like that:

```
array {
   [0] => "1004445",
   [1] => "3087762"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is trivial; have you made any attempt?

Comment: `$new_arr = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $yourarray);`

Comment: I made few attempts with code I have found here and the PHP site but I can not get the result I want....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ways to go about what you want to achieve:

[`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) [`for`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Hint:

```
foreach($array as $inner)
{
    $bin = $inner["clean_bin_number"][0][0];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your input array is:

```
$input = array(
  array("clean_bin_number" => array(array("1004445")) ),
  array("clean_bin_number" => array(array("3087762")) )
);
```

Now you can very easily just iterate over that array and extract the routes/parts you need, or if those exist not only once, iterate over the sub parts.
Example:

```
$new_arr = array();

foreach ($input as $element) {
  $new_arr[] = $element['clean_bin_number'][0][0];
}
```

See this working [here](https://eval.in/143574).

You should have been able to find another solution thou. If not, you have clearly not finished reading/watching beginner tutorials for PHP. Go do that if you want to keep working with PHP. Find Tutorials online like [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVR2UPWH9UQ) or [this article](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/arrays/).

Asking questions to get specific solutions takes longer than actually doing a bit of learning if you ask me.

Comment: @ranslobo where are you getting NULL? 
It is highly unlikely that the $new_arr is NULL since it gets initialised as array and after that values are added as array elements.
Do take that tiny little bit of time to actually check out https://eval.in/143574